# Google Play Game Services + BaseGameUtils added to a Gradle project = package does not exist

Tags: android, dependencies, gradle, google-play-games, build.gradle

I already read many answers on this subject but can't fix my problem, and here it is :

I have a gradle project that is a game, in that game I want to add google game services like I successfully did with 'type-a-number' (which is NOT a gradle project).

But I get the following error:

```
Gradle: error: package com.google.example.games.basegameutils does not exist
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class BaseGameActivity
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable super
```

**NOTE :** in my activity everything that was red because of coming from BaseGameUtils change to normal after the following :

- imported BaseGameUtils as a module, added it as a module dependency to my project and check the 'library mobule' box.
- imported google-play-services.jar as a library
- added to my build.gradle file (the one in my module root) :

  ```
  dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.+'
  }
  ```

  *==> Is there a possibility to add a BaseGameUtils dependencies here ?*
- tried to check/uncheck the export box of BaseGameUtils dependency
- tried to change 'compile' to 'provided'
- change the settings.gradle to

  ```
  include ':MyModule' '(:libraries):BaseGameUtils'
  ```

(one time with :libraries, one time without)

Nothing listed above worked..

What I'm doing wrong ?

What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `settings.gradle` should be:

```
include ':MyModule', ':BaseGameUtils'
```

Note the comma.

Your `build.gradle` for `MyModule` should also have

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.+'
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
}
```

Comment: Ok for the comma, but I get this error now:   Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':MyModule'.
> Project with path ':BaseGamesUtils' could not be found in project ':MyModule'.

Comment: I would specify that it's because the module BaseGameUtils is NOT inside my project like MyModule, so how to point it ?

Comment: @Mino - all modules need to be in the project in IntelliJ/Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

When I was following the step-by-step here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

I was hung up on:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    // ...
}
```

and I just needed to change it to:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
    // ...
}
```

hope that helps someone :)