# Can't import BaseGameUtils - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-games

I AM USING ANDROID STUDIO

I have changed these:

**settings.gradle**

`include: ':app', ':BaseGameUtils'`

**app - build.gradle** (Not "MyGame" build.gradle)

```
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms.play-services:6.1.71'
}
```

**MainActivity.java** (The activity I start first and want to initialize google plus sign-in, etc in)

```
...

import com.google.example.game.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils; (Cannot resolve)

...
```

What am I doing wrong or missing? Anything helps!

Comment: Have you included the BaseGameUtils module in your project?  You can find it at [android-basic-samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)

Comment: pls check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284521/google-play-game-services-basegameutils-added-to-a-gradle-project-package-do

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [instructions here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#setting_up_your_game_project) for properly setting up `BaseGameUtils`. Here is a summary:

1) Download the `android-basic-samples` project from Github.

2) Open your game project and import the module `android-basic-samples/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils` into your project.

3) Update your `build.gradle` dependencies to refer to the module `BaseGameUtils`:

```
dependencies {
    compile(':BaseGameUtils')
    // ...
}
```

Comment: There is no a ```File -> Import Module``` in Android Studio. It seems that the tutorial is not updated :/

Comment: Thanks. 2 days ago I had to import manually, with some additional steps (copying the folder in /libraries/BaseGameUtils and referencing it).

Answer (score 0):

Do not for get to add project :

```
 compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
```