# How can I build the BaseGameUtils Android Project with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, libgdx, google-play-services

I have asked a similar question before but did not receive an answer. I am trying to build the BaseGameUtils helper project from Google that interfaces with their Play Services library. Everything works fine building with Eclipse but I really need to be able to build completely with Gradle. When I try to build using Gradle I get a lot of the following:

error: cannot find symbol
                        activity.getString(R.string.gamehelper_app_misconfigured));

This is a value in an xml file under the res directory of the BaseGameUtils project. I thought maybe Gradle just can't properly see the res folder so I added resources.srcDirs = ['res'] to the build.gradle file. I am basically copying the build.gradle from this google sample:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/build.gradle

What do I need to do to make this work? Why would Gradle not be able to build my project but Eclipse can? There must be some difference between the two. I'm sure someone out there has got this to work?

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284521/google-play-game-services-basegameutils-added-to-a-gradle-project-package-do

Answer (score 0):

To build the library with Android-Studio/Gradle it may help to change the library versions since recent Android-Studio versions expect newer `com.android.tools.build:gradle`dependencies. If you don't build it with Android Studio please add the exact Gradle version and/or IDE you use for building. The following build.gradle file works for me with Android-Studio 1.0-RC2+:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```